# Scrapy request don't get parsed

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

All of my requests don't get parsed. It's successfully parsed though. Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

from boardgamegeek.items import BoardgamegeekItem

class TwoPlayersSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'two_players'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/geeklist/48970',
        'https://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/geeklist/48986'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        bg_ids = ",".join(response.xpath("//item/@objectid").extract())
        yield scrapy.Request("https://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/boardgame/{}".format(bg_ids), self.parse_bg)

    def parse(self, response):
        for bg in response.xpath("//boardgame").extract():
            minplaytime = int(bg.xpath(".//minplaytime/text()").extract_first())
            maxplaytime = int(bg.xpath(".//maxplaytime/text()").extract_first())
            maxplayers = int(bg.xpath(".//maxplayers/text()").extract_first())

            if (minplaytime <= 40 or maxplaytime <= 60) and maxplayers >= 3:
                i = BoardgamegeekItem()
                i["link"] = "http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/{}".format(bg.xpath(".//objectid").extract_first())
                i["title"] = bg.xpath(".//name/text()").extract_first()
                i["minplayers"] = int(bg.xpath(".//minplayers/text()").extract_first())
                i["maxplayers"] = maxplayers
                i["minplaytime"] = minplaytime
                i["maxplaytime"] = maxplaytime

                yield i
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it! It happened because I had two parse function with the exact same name! I forgot to update one of the parse name to `parse_bg`